# Birt report - hidden cross tab cells showing in excel

Tags: birt

I have a cross tab. I hide an entire column by setting the style to one containing "display: none". This looks great in html and pdf.

But when exporting to Excel, the column appears with empty values.

How do I force the excel export to not show the column?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the visibility expression for the column instead of the style display:none?

Comment: I dont see a visibility expression option in Properties to set.

Comment: If I set the cells visibility to false, it behaves the same as using a hidden style; hidden in html but empty column in excel.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, I thought you meant a table item.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting width to 0 only hide the column (when exporting to excel) when the report Layout is "Fixed Layout".

Unfortunately "Fixed Layout" is a pain to use when you have a crosstab with lots of columns, as Excel starts throwing errors if the width gets too big.